# Excel 2013 - VBA - Copy to next open row on target workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have been able to get quite far on my project by using a lot of the solutions posted on here. Unfortunately, I simply cannot workout the bugs and could really use some help. What I am trying to accomplish is as follows:

-"CNC WORK ORDER REQUEST - V2.XLSM" is the source workbook where a department will input their requests for any sort of CNC work. I have formatted it so the output is consistent. A whole department of people will have access to it on their local computers.

-"MASTER SCHEDULE.XLSX" is the target workbook where I would like a particular range of cells copied to, on the next available row of cells in this workbook. This workbook is for upper management to have visibility on a "master schedule" that is created by the submissions of the CNC WORK ORDER REQUEST workbook.

I do feel that the WORKORDER REQUEST is fine, but I am having issue with copying to the next open row of cells on the MASTER SCHEDULE. I cannot get all of the cells to copy to the next open row.

The code I have is as follows:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

MsgBox "Welcome, please enter information in *ALL* subsquent prompts as instructed."

Dim Customer
Customer = InputBox("Enter customer name")
Range("e1") = Customer

Dim Job
Job = InputBox("Enter Job#")
Range("e2") = Job

Dim JobName
JobName = InputBox("Enter job name / description")
Range("e3") = JobName

Dim TodaysDate
TodaysDate = InputBox("Enter today's date")
Range("E4") = TodaysDate

Dim Manager
Manager = InputBox("Enter your Intials")
Range("e5") = Manager

MsgBox "Before entering which machine will run this part, you must get this information from Ronnie", vbOKOnly

Dim Machine
Machine = InputBox("Enter which machine this will be run on. Options are: Thermwood -or- MultiCam")
Range("b9") = Machine

Dim Part
Part = InputBox("Enter part name as per drawing")
Range("B10") = Part

Dim Qty
Qty = InputBox("Enter Qty needed including overs")
Range("B11") = Qty

Dim Material
Material = InputBox("Enter material type with details")
Range("B12") = Material

Dim Thickness
Thickness = InputBox("Enter material thickness")
Range("b13") = Thickness

Dim EdgeFinish
EdgeFinish = InputBox("Enter edge finish for this part - MILL FINISH, FLAME POLISH, DIAMOND POLISH, DIAMOND AND BUFF")
Range("B14") = EdgeFinish

Dim MaterialInHouse
Material = InputBox("If material is in house, type YES, if not, enter the ETA")
Range("B15") = MaterialInHouse

Dim AddtionalProcessing
AddtionalProcessing = InputBox("Please note any subsequent processing required")
Range("B16") = AddtionalProcessing

Dim NeedBy
NeedBy = InputBox("Enter required completion date for parts")
Range("B17") = NeedBy

Dim AddtionalNotes
AddtionalNotes = InputBox("Enter any additional notes, if required")
Range("B18") = AddtionalNotes

'TESTING - TO COPY ABOVE VALUES TO MASTER SCHEDULE'
'Dim wbk As Workbook
'Dim strFirstFile As String
'Dim strSecondFile As String

'strFirstFile = "CNC WORK ORDER REQUEST - V2.XLSM"

'strSecondFile = "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\MASTER SCHEDULE.XLSX" 'CHANGE TO TARGET FILE ONCE DETERMINED

'CUSTOMER COPY:
'Set wbk = Workbooks(strFirstFile)
'With wbk.Sheets("sheet1")
'.Range("E1").Copy
'End With
'Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)
'With wbk.Sheets("sheet1").Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
'End With

'JOB# COPY:
'Set wbk = Workbooks(strFirstFile)
'With wbk.Sheets("sheet1")
'.Range("E2").Copy
'End With
'Set wbk = Workbooks(strSecondFile)
'With wbk.Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
'End With


'wbk.Save
'wbk.Close

'END TESTING


MsgBox "Please print and submit to Ronnie.", vbOKOnly 'ADD COMMENT BELOW BACK UP HERE ONCE SCHEDULE COMPLETE
'Workorder has already been uploaded to schedule",

End Sub
```

Sorry if I did not articulate myself well enough with what I'm trying to accomplish. I tried posting images, but was not allowed.  I am really looking forward to solving this as it will help organize the company I am working with. Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Mike Q

Comment: You are getting rid of the comment indicators before each line when you run this, correct?

Comment: Hi D_Zab -- I have commented out the section which I am having trouble with. It should not be commented out, though. Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the issue? This looks as though the "Customer" and "Job" should each go into the last row of the column you specified on "sheet1". Are some values being copied over?

Comment: Kyle - thanks for your response. Currently, the only cell being copied is the  "customer", no others. Additionally, when I open another instance of the REQUEST, it copies over existing values -- it does not go down to the next available row in the SCHEDULE. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the sheets it's impossible for me to know where to paste to, but it looks like your problem is your only copying one cell at a time so that's all that will copy. You need to copy the entire range and then if you paste it to the first open cell in your destination sheet it will paste everything.

You will probably still need to tweak this a bit but hopefully it will give you enough to work with:

```
'TESTING - TO COPY ABOVE VALUES TO MASTER SCHEDULE'
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim strFirstFile As String
Dim strSecondFile As String

strFirstFile = "CNC WORK ORDER REQUEST - V2.XLSM"
strSecondFile = "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\MASTER SCHEDULE.XLSX"

'CUSTOMER Copy:
Set wbk = Workbooks(strFirstFile)
wbk.Sheets("sheet1").Range("E1:E5").Copy

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)
wbk.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

'JOB# Copy:
Set wbk = Workbooks(strFirstFile)
wbk.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B9:B18").Copy
Set wbk = Workbooks(strSecondFile)
wbk.Sheets("sheet1").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 


wbk.Save
wbk.Close

'END TESTING
```

Just an FYI, if you're looking for the user to input a lot of data check into making a userform. They're not hard to make and will be much easier for your users to input a bunch of data. It also gives you some control over validating it.

Comment: Hi D_Zab, thank you for your input. I copied your code so that I could try to manipulate it, but I got stuck on the following line: 'code'wbk.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count + 1).PasteSpecial'code' this generated an Run-time error 1004. Application-define or object-defined error.  I did try to post a picture so that it would be easier to visualize the objective, but I did not have enough rep. Could you kindly advise what we can do to move past this?

Comment: I made a mistake, try it now.

Comment: Hi D_Zab -- I tested your code but still received the same 1004 RT error, sorry. Can you kindly let me know what we can change? Thanks